# 20.10: How do I undo a file operation?

Tags: 20.10, filemanager

I dragged some files into the wrong folder and now I want to undo that. Where do I find the undo option?

I looked in the right click context menu and in the hamburger menu in the top right of the file manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the Undo feature is hidden in the drop-down menu used for folder appearance settings, i.e. the downward arrow next to the hamburger menu.

Very hard to discover considering it has nothing to do with appearance.

Comment: Indeed, discoverability can be an issue with these modern hamburger and other menus, but once you know... Ctrl+z is also a possibility, and there should be a notification shortly after your move allowing to redo.

Comment: Truth be told, UI & UX aren't necessarily Linux strengths. The good news is you can change and/or report it with hopes that the devs agree and make the changes for you. Never be afraid to seek out the devs to give constructive criticism.

Comment: @KGIII Thank you for the encouragement. I'm just pretty disillusioned with the way reports are handled in many such projects, and I've come to the conclusion that it's more productive to share workarounds here than to grow old watching bugs never get touched and then get closed with the justification "this report is so old... so much has changed since then", or hearing "we know you took pains to follow our bug reporting guidelines to the letter, but could you please also register on this, this and this bug tracker and repeat the process in whatever format they prefer?"

Comment: I don't mind leaving feedback or reporting bugs. Or arguing for a design change for that matter, I've just found so few projects interested in that aspect. Some reject the idea before even hearing the rationale.